# Disable Lightbox Plus for mobile devices

Tags: mobile, scroll, lightbox

I'm making a mobile version of a website, and there are a lot of lightboxes used. I'm trying to find a way to either add scrolling to the lightboxes on mobile devices or just disable the lightbox plugin altogether if using a mobile device to view. Tried this code, but couldn't get it to work. http://chris-barr.com/index.php/entry/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/ Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the scrolling issue by adding the following CSS to the parent elements that hold the iframe, div tag or image:

```
#cboxLoadedContent, #cboxContent{
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lightboxOnResize = function lightboxOnResize() {
if ($(window).width() < 960) { alert();
    $('a[rel="lightbox"]')
        .removeProp('rel')
        .addClass('lightboxRemoved');
} else {
    $('a.lightboxRemoved').prop('rel', 'lightbox');
}
```

}

$(document).ready(lightboxOnResize);
$(window).resize(lightboxOnResize);

could be used ..can change viewport width as per your requirment !!